# What does "rule" mean in "the rule of law"?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, etymology, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

What does *rule* mean in *the rule of law*? I understand the concept of it, but not the grammar. Does "rule" mean "control"/"domination"? Or does it mean "rule" as in "rules for chess"?

Personally, I find the former meaning to be more intuitive, as it sort of fits the definition (since nobody is above the law, law is the thing that rules [controls]). Moreover, Aristotle referred to this concept as: "It is more proper that law should govern than any one of the citizens" (per [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_law).)

But could it mean the latter? [This article](https://www.lawteacher.net/free-law-essays/constitutional-law/introduction-concept-of-rule-law-essays.php) says the phrase "is derived from the French phrase ‘la principe de legalite’ (the principle of legality)". So could its meaning be "When enforcing laws, an invisible *law*/*rule*/*principle* of law itself exists, which is: nobody is above the law"?

Honestly, I was quite stumped when I first heard of this phrase. Thus, any and all help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: _Rule_ is what kings do. _The Rule of Law_ implies that the law is more important than any human ruler.

Comment: The short answer is: the first of the two senses that you list. However, the rule of law is partially defined by some broad rules,  in the second of the two senses (although *principles* would be a better term), such as the rules/principles that the laws generally must be published and must not be retroactive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In “the rule of law”, **rule** is a mass noun (and a verbal noun – from the verb<sup>†</sup> “to rule”) and indicates the concept of imposition of authority.

Thus *the rule of law* implies *such legislation and customary practice that form the basis of the implementation of administrative power and hence popular regulation.*

The OED gives **rule of law** as a complex noun:

> 1 **The authority and influence of law in society, esp. when viewed as a constraint on individual and institutional behaviour; (hence) the principle whereby all members of a society (including those in government) are considered equally subject to publicly disclosed legal codes and processes.**
>
> ?c1500   J. Blount tr. N. Upton Essent. Portions De Studio Militari (1931) 33   *Lawes And constitutcions be ordeyned be cause the noysome Appetit of man maye be kepte vnder the Rewle of lawe by the wiche mankinde ys dewly enformed to lyue honestly [etc.].*
>
> 1996   Counsel Mar. 22/2   *This may prove a nice earner for the Treasury, but the rule of law is intended to protect citizens from the state, not just to punish criminals.*

**<sup>†</sup> 3. a.** intransitive. **Of a person: to govern, to reign; to hold supreme command or authority.**

**b.** intransitive. **In extended use of a thing: to have a presiding authority or influence.**

1998   Z. Sardar Postmodernism & Other iv. 153   *Postmodernism triumphs only where ignorance rules.*

Comment: So the affording of the highest authority to the law, usually as decreed by the legislative and interpreted / meted out by the judiciary (and enforced by the executive). Not immediately to the rich and/or powerful, or to what is generally considered locally expedient.

Answer (score 7):

Apparently its origin is from Ancient Greece. Its meaning refers to the concept of being ruled by the law rather than a single ruler.

> [The Rule of Law](https://education.nationalgeographic.org/resource/rule-law/#:%7E:text=The%20Rule%20of%20Law%20has,leader%20or%20the%20best%20laws.) has its origins in ancient Greece and, more specifically, in the philosophy of Aristotle. In his work titled Politics, Aristotle raised the question of whether it is better to be ruled by the best leader or the best laws. In exploring this question he found advantages and disadvantages to both governing methods. His conclusion, however, suggested that laws were appropriate for most societies since they were carefully thought out and could be applied to most situations. Therefore, people should be ruled by the best laws.

(nationalgeographic.org)

Comment: The question indicates that the OP is already aware of this, and is not seeking an account of the history of the idea of the rule of law, but of the **wording** that is used to express it **in English**.

Comment: @jsw29 yes! the very first sentence of the source that user 66974 cited states: "The Rule of Law is a ***principle*** that all people and organizations within a country, state, or community are held accountable to the same set of laws." I am very, very confused and still without a definite answer.